# How to build for JDK 1.1.8?

Tags: java, ant

I need to find a good way to build for JDK 1.1.8. So far I've tried using Eclipse, IntelliJ and Ant with no luck. With Ant (v 1.7.1) I tried setting the relevant parameters on the javac task (`executable` and `compiler`). Trouble is this:

> [javac] This version of java does not support the classic compiler; upgrading to modern.

Is there a way to make Ant work, or perhaps some other way?

Comment: +1 just to bear you up! I'll think about you next time when I feel lack of new technologies in my current project.

Comment: There are valid reasons to target 1.1 JVMs. Embedded systems are one of them.

Comment: Yes, it's supposed to run on a Windows CE machine. Thanks for the moral support. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set the `target="1.1"` and `source="1.3"` attributes on the `javac` ant task (source=1.3 is required for target=1.1).

Note that this will give you 1.1-compatible class files, but you still need to make sure you don't use any APIs or features not supported in your target JVM.

**Edit:** As pointed out by Andrew Thompson, you can use the `bootclasspath` option to make `javac` compile against 1.1.8 APIs (note that in JDK 1.1.8, the runtime library was called `classes.zip`, not `rt.jar`).

Comment: To ensure the missing "APIs or features" problem does not trip up the build, also specify a -bootclasspath pointing to a 1.1.8 rt.jar.

Comment: Yes it works! Please incorporate the comment into the answer to make it complete.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I've updated the answer with the `bootclasspath` information.